# Is there any function in python that does some tasks like Conditional Formatting in excel does?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-formatting

I wanna export a table in my python code by the "to_excel" function to an excel file. But I don't want to catch a raw table! I wanna do some graphical changes on it but not in excel and with the Conditional Formatting option. I want to do those changes in python code!

Actually, I have not found a library or function to do this!

Comment: Now you found them, what did you find?

Comment: You can use `openpyxl` to add conditional formatting to an existing `.xlsx` file. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html